# How can bypass startup time in Ubuntu 14.04 server?

Tags: 14.04, server

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 server in oracle VirtualBox But when I start the Ubuntu server it takes 5.15 minutes each time. How I can overcome it?
[for simplicity click this link to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lvGD.png)

output of **cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
#Myadded configuretion
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

output of **ip addr**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:19:bc:70 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.5/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe19:bc70/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:34:05:2b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe34:52b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You could a) configure your network interfaces correctly or b) remove the trouble making interface from your network configuration. Both is usually done in `/etc/network/interfaces` or c) please post output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` to your question and format it as code so someone may find an error in your config

Comment: @derHugo thank you to provide me a valuable information.

Comment: After booting you could check which of the interfaces is not configured by running `ifconfig -a`. This displays your interfaces with some information including the IPs. So the trouble making interface is the one with no IP or an unexpected one

Answer (score 0):

Either one of the above interfaces `enp0s3` or `enp0s8` does not get an address through dhcp. What is the output of `ip addr`?

`enp0s8` is the culprit. Just comment out the entries and you're good to go:

```
#auto enp0s8
#iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

Comment: please see the question again, I had added the output of ip addr.

Comment: i have answered. Please check my answer again. Comment out the lines for the not connected interface.

Comment: Did the above solve your problem?

Comment: Yes I have done it and it works for me without delay. thank you.